# Fail to invoke \g(\f(x))

Tags: pstricks

I want to invoke `\g(\f(x))` which is equal to `x` actually. However the following does not compile in PostScript stage (I think). Could you fix it? I am not asking how to plot `y=x` but how to invoke the composition function `\g(\f(x))`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f(#1){((#1-2)/(2*(#1)+1))}% y=f(x)
\def\g(#1){((2+#1)/(1-2*(#1)))}% y=g(x) in which g is the inverse of f.

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4,-4)(6,6)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt}
    \psplot{-4}{5}{\g(\f(x))}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\def\f#1{((#1-2)/(2*(#1)+1))}
\def\g#1{((2+#1)/(1-2*(#1)))}` and `\psplot{-4}{5}{\g{\f{x}}}`, i.e. the usual curly braces instead of round ones. When you use `\def\f(#1)` you are using delimited arguments which have problems when you nest calls (like the `[` and `]` of optional arguments)

Comment: It is the same situation as for `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]`. The inner `[...]` have to be braced.

Comment: @Herbert: I found a bug in `\pstTriangle`. It cannot accept `Rand`. For example: `\pstTriangle(0,0){A}(3,4){B}(!.5 Rand sub 10 mul 3){C}` does not compile.

Comment: `tx@Dict begin Rand end`

Comment: @Herbert: Th anks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of similar parameter text for `\f` and `\g` is what causes the problem here. The *first* occurrence of a `(`...`)` pair is used to extract the arguments. So, in

```
\g(\f(<x>))
```

passes the incomplete `\f(<x>` as the argument to `\g`. To get around this, brace the argument to avoid confusion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f(#1){((#1-2)/(2*(#1)+1))}% y=f(x)
\def\g(#1){((2+#1)/(1-2*(#1)))}% y=g(x) in which g is the inverse of f.

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4,-4)(6,6)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psset{linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt}
  \psplot{-4}{5}{\g({\f(x)})}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```